# Как перевести SQL запрос в строку?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как перевести SQL запрос в строку?

```
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.dicts', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.dicts;  
GO  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.get_status', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.get_status;  
GO  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.get_typ_act', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.get_typ_act;  
GO  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getuser_name', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getuser_name;  
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_typ_act(@typ int)
returns varchar(256)
as
begin
    DECLARE @ret varchar(256)
    if @typ = 0
    select @ret = 'Неопределенное суд. дело';
    if @typ = 1
    select @ret = 'Приказ';
    if @typ = 2
    select @ret = 'Иск';
    if @typ = 3
    select @ret = 'Правопреемство';
    if @typ = 4
    select @ret = 'Банкротство';
    return @ret
end;
go
```

Ранее просто вставлял в нотпад++ и заменял \r\n на " " и все прекрасно работало. Сейчас при таком образе выдает ошибки у каждой функции.

Сам запрос необходимо перенести в строку для того, чтобы отправлять запрос через OdbcConnect C# + докинуть в него where

UPD: Если перевести весь запрос в строку и попробовать вбить в SSMS выдает:
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "GO"

Answer (score 1):

`go` - это *команда* SSMS. Такого ключевого слова нет в SQL.

Поэтому нужно удалить все `go` из sql-запроса.

Кроме того, `CREATE FUNCTION` может быть только единственным выражением в батче (пакете) SQL. Команда `go` как раз и разделяет код на батчи.

В C# этот код можно выполнить послав несколько отдельных запросов с помощью `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, наверное, можно?

```
var str = "     IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.dicts', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  \r\n    DROP FUNCTION dbo.dicts;  \r\nGO  \r\nIF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.get_status', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  \r\n    DROP FUNCTION dbo.get_status;  \r\nGO  \r\nIF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.get_typ_act', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  \r\n    DROP FUNCTION dbo.get_typ_act;  \r\nGO  \r\nIF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getuser_name', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  \r\n    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getuser_name;  \r\nGO\r\nCREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_typ_act(@typ int)\r\nreturns varchar(256)\r\nas\r\nbegin\r\n    DECLARE @ret varchar(256)\r\n    if @typ = 0\r\n    select @ret = 'Неопределенное суд. дело';\r\n    if @typ = 1\r\n    select @ret = 'Приказ';\r\n    if @typ = 2\r\n    select @ret = 'Иск';\r\n    if @typ = 3\r\n    select @ret = 'Правопреемство';\r\n    if @typ = 4\r\n    select @ret = 'Банкротство';\r\n    return @ret\r\nend;\r\ngo"
```

И, мне кажется, go в конце не нужен...

Comment: Нет. Просто написать его в строку не поможет. Я уже так пробовал. Постоянно одна и та же ошибка

"ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "GO".

Comment: Ну я и говорю, в конце go не нужен

Comment: Полный запрос: https://text-host.ru/bez-zagolovka-1038
Список ошибок: http://ontext.info/150928